# Macro to calculate maximum value

Tags: z3

I found the macro to calculate the maximum value in `Z3 Sat Solver`.

```
(define-fun max_integ ((x Int) (y Int)) Int 
    (ite (< x y) y x))
```

How to program the same using C-API in `Z3 Sat Solver`?

Thank You,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `define-fun` command is just creating a macro. Note that the SMT 2.0 standard doesn’t allow recursive definitions. Z3 will expand every occurrence of `max_integ` during parsing time. The command `define-fun` may be used to make the input file simpler and easier to read, but internally it does not really help Z3.
This issue is discussed in the following posts:

- [Equivalent of define-fun in Z3 API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7740556/equivalent-of-define-fun-in-z3-api/7745041#7745041)
- [Z3 SMT 2.0 vs Z3 py implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13826217/z3-smt-2-0-vs-z3-py-implementation)